# Is there a built in mechanism for Miles/KM interchangeability for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization

I am currently working on a map-based iPhone application and wish to display some information to the user.  For my application, it makes sense to have a setting of some sort where the user can choose Miles or Kilometers.  Is there a built in mechanism (maybe similar to string localization) for doing this kind of value switching so that I can avoid an if-block around each time I want to display something to the user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [NSLocale](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You should be able to get the current locale using [NSLocale currentLocale]. Then call [theLocale objectForKey: NSLocaleMeasurementSystem] and look at the results which should tell you if the users locale uses the metric system. The docs for NSLocale have a constants section which list all of the values that can be passed to the locale.

Using this you would make your own function that could be used in your program to return your distance in a locale specific way.

Comment: If you want a simple boolean value, you could also check the NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem key, which returns an NSNumber-wrapped boolean value for whether to use kilometers or miles.

Comment: In my application, I intend to give the user the option of having things displayed in miles or kilometers.  Based on the feedback on this thread, I think it's clear that there is not a built-in mechanism of interchanging one unit for the other, but it won't be too difficult to just have a method that checks the user-set boolean and does a conversion to kilometers. Thanks for the responses. I'm sure they'll come in handy for me at some point.

Comment: This method would still be useful for initially populating your preference with the users system choice for units. Something to consider.

Comment: The issue with using NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem is that you'll get a broad view of whether metric is used generally, in that locale. However, some countries are predominantly metric, but still use miles for road distances and speed (for example, the UK). As such, I always use NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem to seed the initial default, but then expose the display units as a user-configurable setting within the app so the user can change it. This accommodates preferences that don't always match up with locale. Think of the Canadian that is now living in the USA, but still thinks in kilometers, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my quick test `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem` may not work for finding if the users' region uses kilometers or miles.

In the U.K, the distances are in Miles and speed in  Miles per hour but `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem` returns 1.

In the U.S, `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem` returns 0 which is correct (distance is in Miles and speed in Miles per hour).

In India, `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem`returns 1 which is correct again (distance is in Kilometers and spee in kph).